# Java integer to hex and to int

Tags: java, integer, hex, type-conversion

I have the problem, that the method does not work as expected. In most cases it works. However there is a case it does not work.
I have a byte array containing some values. In hex e.g.: 0x04 0x42 (littleEndian). If I use the method convertTwoBytesToInt, I get a really small number. It should be > 16000 and not smaller than 2000.

I have two methods:

```
private static int convertTwoBytesToInt(byte[] a){
    String f1 = convertByteToHex(a[0]);
    String f2 = convertByteToHex(a[1]);
    return Integer.parseInt(f2+f1,RADIX16);
}

private static byte[] convertIntToTwoByte(int value){
    byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();
    System.out.println("Check: "+Arrays.toString(bytes));
    byte[] result = new byte[2];
    //big to little endian:
    result[0] = bytes[3];
    result[1] = bytes[2];
    return result;
}
```

I call them as follows:

```
    byte[] h = convertIntToTwoByte(16000);
    System.out.println("AtS: "+Arrays.toString(h));
    System.out.println("tBtInt: "+convertTwoBytesToInt(h));
```

If I use the value 16000, there is no problem, but if I use 16900, the integer value of "convertTwoBytesToInt" is 1060.

Any Idea?

Comment: Why are you doing it in such a convoluted way, instead of for example `int b = a[0] << 8 | a[1];`?

Comment: @Kayaman - I agree about using bit manipulation, but your suggestion doesn't work for byte values greater than 0x7f because of sign extension.

Comment: Please show code in  `convertByteToHex()`

Comment: private static String convertByteToHex(byte b) {
        int i = b & 0xFF;
        return Integer.toHexString(i);
    }

Comment: @TedHopp You're right, and now I can't even edit to the correct (but a bit more convoluted) version `int b = (a[1] | (a[0] << 8)) & 0xFFFF;`

Comment: @Kayaman - That still isn't correct: when `a[1] > 0x7f`, the sign extension of `a[1]` will wipe out `(a[0] << 8)` with all 1s.

Comment: Damnit. One more try. `int b = (a[0] << 8 | (a[1] & 0xFF)) & 0xFFFF;`.

Comment: My original point of "less convoluted way" is long gone, and probably `|` has higher precedence than `<<` and the above version is missing parentheses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you provided, my guess is that `convertByteToHex(byte)` is converting to a single-digit hex string when the byte value is less than 0x10. 16900 is 0x4204 and 1060 is 0x424.

You need to ensure that the conversion is zero-padded to two digits.

A much simpler approach is to use bit manipulation to construct the `int` value from the bytes:

```
private static int convertTwoBytesToInt(byte[] a) {
    return ((a[1] & 0xff) << 8) | (a[0] & 0xff);
}
```

Comment: Yes, at first glance it seems smart, to implement it in that way, but now... it was not really smart.

Comment: Thank you! :-) now i have to check if the result of the computation is as i wanted.